# sql query for left join in mysql for primary key in table1 and table2 are not same

Tags: mysql

I've got the following two SQL tables (in MySQL):

```
customers
+----+------+--------------+
| id | Name | City         |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | John | New york     |
+----+------+--------------+
| 2  | Jane | Paris        |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | Jeph | California   |
+----+------+--------------+
| 4 | Mike  | Singapore    |
+----+------+--------------+
products
+----+------+--------------+
| id | proId| proName      |
+----+------+--------------+
| 1  | 0945 | Laptop       |
+----+------+--------------+
| 2  | 0950 | Mobile       |
+----+------+--------------+
| 3  | 1045 | Tablet       |
+----+------+--------------+
| 10 | 1048 | Ipod         |
+----+------+--------------+
```

what will be the query to find id which are not same in two tables ? The desired output would be:

```
Call
+----+------+--------------+
| id | proId|Name          |
+----+------+--------------+
| 4  | Null | Mike         |
+----+------+--------------+
| 10 | 1048 | Null         |
+----+------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since MySQL has no **FULL** OUTER JOIN, you have to use a UNION with two LEFT JOINs:

```
SELECT c.id, p.proID, c.Name
FROM customers AS c LEFT JOIN products AS p ON c.id = p.id
WHERE p.id IS NULL
UNION
SELECT p.id, p.proID, c.Name
FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN customers AS c ON p.id = c.id
WHERE c.id IS NULL
;
```